# I am making a login page for my c# forms in Visual Basic 2017 and got an error everytime I try to login using the correct credentials

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms, authentication, visual-studio-2017

When I have my login button pressed I got this error

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUf3j.png)

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection (@"C:\LOGIN\DB\LOGINDB.MDF");
    string query = "Select * from Table where username='" + txtUsername.Text + "'and password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dtbl);
    if(dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        frmMain objFrmMain = new frmMain();
        this.Hide();
        objFrmMain.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Check you things");
    }
}
```

and my sql tables:

[Main table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh7Sh.png)

[and this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc3iX.png)

Comment: An unsecured database, SQL injection attack-ready code *and* plain-text credentials being stored?

Comment: Did you debug the code? Did you check what error you are getting? Can you share the error message here?

Comment: surround yr code with try/catch and include the exception in yr question, plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your path is correct .
Your connection strong should have data source and etc. Your format is totally wrong

```
Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true;
AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;User Instance=true;
```

More about connection string is here
[connection string guide](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)
After you declare ur sql connection.
You need to open your connection

Sqlcon.open();

Comment: I added these changes to my code:
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =.\SQLExpress; AttachDbFilename = C:\LOGIN\DB\LOGINDB.MDF;Integrated Security = true;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance = True;");

and added sqlcon.Open(); in the if section

Comment: then i got this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'

Comment: Take out the sqlcon. Open from if section just before you call to connect to database .  If you put inside the if section. By that time your connection is not even open. How you expect it to retrieve data ?

Comment: Like I said. If you don’t know where to put . Put at after your variable declaration